# BI Publisher cannot retain the fraction for excel output

Tags: excel, text, overriding

I am trying to display data which is in fraction .

Example : I want to display 1/8 ,5/32 in Excel.

The XML file has 1/8 ,5/32 as the data but when I publish it in Excel using BI publisher the data is converted to dates Jan-8 .
How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: i tried the suggestion on the below link , however it did not work :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335486/oracle-bi-publisher-how-to-format-numbers-as-text-so-that-leading-zeroes-dont

Comment: If you prepend the data with a single quote that will force display as text